# Why does mocha-webpack search component in test folder instead of app folder?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webpack, mocha.js

I just started using mocha as my unit test library, but currently I stumbled on a problem when I run the `npm run test`, which throw this message:

```
WEBPACK  Failed to compile with 1 error(s)

Error in ./test/my-app/test-TermConditionContent.spec.js

  Module not found: './components/UI/TermConditionContent' in '/home/user/my-project/dir/my-app/test/my-app'
```

the mocha-webpack searched in its test folder instead of `dir`

Here is my project structure:

```
/home
 /my-project
  /dir
   /my-app
    /applications
      /my-sub-app-1
      /my-sub-app-2
    /test
      /my-sub-app-1
       /test-TermConditionContent.spec.js
      /my-sub-app-2
    package.json
    webpack.config-test.js
```

Here is my `test` command inside `package.json`:

```
 "test": "mocha-webpack --require ignore-styles --require babel-core/register --require jsdom-global/register --webpack-config webpack.config-test.js 'test/my-app/test-*.spec.{jsx,js}'"
```

Note:

- I'm using webpack and babel
- I already installed mocha-webpack
- It works fine with the regular mocha, but I need to fix the import path of the tested files and its dependencies to its relative path. This costs a lot of time

Does anybody experienced this, can anybody explain how to solve this?

I'm suspecting it's the faulty webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing:

```
var TermConditionContent = require('./components/UI/TermConditionContent')
```

to

```
var TermConditionContent = require('/components/UI/TermConditionContent')
```

and resolving the path inside webpack config.